# What is zero-order transmission spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, experimental-physics, photons, terminology

In the paper [The extraordinary optical transmission through subwavelength hole arrays by T. W. Ebbesen](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v391/n6668/abs/391667a0.html) it is shown at particular wavelength there is a peak observed in zero order transmission spectrum. I am not understanding what exactly this [zero order transmission spectrum](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=zero+order+transmission+spectrum) means?

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the "zero order transmission spectrum" naming comes from considering the hole array as a transmission grating.

(Illustration of the different orders of a transmission grating [here](https://www.edmundoptics.com/globalassets/commerce/products/1939_incident_beam.gif), for example.)

The zero order is just the beam that goes straight through the hole array with no deviation.